# Translate an entire Google Sheet using Google Translate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-translate

I have a Google Sheet written in the Japanese Language. I need to convert it into English.

I know we can use `googletranslate(<sheet!:cell>, <input_language>, <output_language>)` to translate.

But without a script, this forces me to translate each and every row. I need a script that will convert my whole Google Sheet into English.

I prefer if it's converted into a separate sheet. Please let me know of the possible solutions.

TIA

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. About `I have to do it for each and every row`, in this case, all cells have to translate? 2. I cannot understand about `It would be better if its converted into a separate sheet`.

Comment: @Tanaike I will show you an example 

Row 1 Col 1 
Row 1 Col 1 
Row 1 Col 1

Comment: @Tanaike I would be inclined to keep the original "untranslated sheet" intact (as a historical record), and create a new sheet for the translation. I think this is what the questioner is suggesting..

Comment: @Navaneetha Krishnan K Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for replying. From `a separate sheet`, I couldn't understand whether OP wants to copy the source Spreadsheet to other Spreadsheet or wants to copy one of sheets to the same Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about this. I have to apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike I will show you an example 

Row 1 Col  1   Japanese lang     

Row 2 Col 2   Japanese lang           

Row 3 Col 3   Japanese lang        

Row 2 Col  1 Japanese lang    

Row 2 Col 2   Japanese lang           

Row 3 Col 3    Japanese lang     

Row 3 Col 1   Japanese lang     

Row 3 Col 2   Japanese lang          

Row 3 Col 3   Japanese lang      

instead of translating line by line 
=Googletranslate("A1","ja","en"),

Googletranslate("A2","ja","en"),

Googletranslate("A3","ja","en").

Can we have a function to convert whole sheet ? do u understand now

Comment: @Navaneetha Krishnan K Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm about your question. 1. do you want to translate all cells from Japanese to English? 2. Do you want to translate all cells in all sheets in a Spreadsheet? 3. In this case, do you want to copy all translated sheets to the same Spreadsheet? or do you want to copy all translated sheets to a new Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike

1)  Yes I would like to convert all cells from Japanese to English .

2) I would be better if I convert in a separate sheet and not spreadsheet . 

3) Copy all translated sheets to the same spreadsheet .

Answer (score 3):

### Understanding

- You want to translate Japanese to English for all cells of all sheets in a Spreadsheet.
- You want to copy the sheet with the translated values to the same Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this answer, Class LanguageApp is used.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, each cell is translated with `LanguageApp.translate()`.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet. And run `myFunction` at the script editor. By this, all cells of all sheets in the Spreadsheet are translated from Japanese to English. And the translated values are put to the inserted sheet in the same Spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const s = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(`translated_${sheet.getSheetName()}`);
    const range = s.getDataRange();
    const translatedValues = range.getDisplayValues().map(r => r.map(c => {
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
      return LanguageApp.translate(c, "ja", "en");
    }));
    range.setValues(translatedValues);
  });
}
```

- In this case, each cell is translated. So from the specification, `Utilities.sleep(1000)` (waiting 1 second) is required to be used. By this, when there are a lot of cells, the process time might be long.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, all cells from a sheet are retrieved and converted to a string value, then the string value is translated. And the translated values are put to the sheet.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of the Spreadsheet. And run `myFunction` at the script editor. By this, all cells of all sheets in the Spreadsheet are translated from Japanese to English. And the translated values are put to the inserted sheet in the same Spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const s = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(`translated_${sheet.getSheetName()}`);
    const range = s.getDataRange();
    const delimiter = "#";
    const sourceValues = range.getDisplayValues().map(r => r.join(delimiter)).join("\n");
    const translatedValues = Utilities.parseCsv(LanguageApp.translate(sourceValues, "ja", "en"), delimiter.charCodeAt(0));
    range.setValues(translatedValues);
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  });
}
```

- In this case, the values of all cells are translated by one request of `LanguageApp.translate()`. By this, the process time will be shorter than the pattern 1. But if the values are large, an error might occur. About this, I'm not sure.
- In above script, `#` is used as the delimiter for converting to the string value. If `#` is used in the cells, please change the character.

### Note:

- This modified script is run with enabling V8.

### Reference:

- [Class LanguageApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/language-app)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, but I needed to have multiple language support and I didn't want any significant delay, nor did I want to worry whether the source cells were already in my desired destination language, so I came up with this solution.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Translations')
    .addItem('Japanese > English', 'jpToEn')
    .addToUi();
}

function jpToEn() {
  translate('jp','en')
}

function translate(inputLang, outputLang) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dest = sheet.copyTo(ss);
  dest.setName(`${inputLang}_${outputLang}_${sheet.getName()}`)
  var range = dest.getDataRange();
  var formula = "=iferror(googletranslate('" + sheet.getName() + "'!" + "R[0]C[0],\"" + inputLang +"\",\"" + outputLang + "\"),\"\")";
  range.setFormulaR1C1(formula);
}
```

As you can see, this adds a menu to to your Google Sheets document. You can make yours translate however you desire, as many different languages as you need.  Just extend the menu or replace the items already there.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is quite simple without using any scripts or add-ons.

I created a new sheet an on A1 cell I put a formula:

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(Sheet1!A1, "ru", "en")
```

This gave me a translation of my `A1` cell from `Sheet1`.

Next I just copied this formula to all other cells in my new `Sheet2`. Voila, you have the translation.

However, Google Translate is quite bad with translating Russian into English in Google Sheets, so I had to change it by cutting all cells in `Sheet2` and pasting "Only Values" back again. This gives you translated cells that can be modified.