# Google Sheets Translate a column to another column with Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-translate

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824929/translate-entire-google-spreadsheet-with-google-translate) script translates, from Japanese to English, all text in a sheet to another tab.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const s = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(`translated_${sheet.getSheetName()}`);
    const range = s.getDataRange();
    const translatedValues = range.getDisplayValues().map(r => r.map(c => {
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
      return LanguageApp.translate(c, "ja", "en");
    }));
    range.setValues(translatedValues);
  });
}
```

Instead, to translate column A and put the results into column B, while not triming the blank cells, how would the script be in that case?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed. @Cooper ?

Comment: That's a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to translate column A from Japanese to English, put the results in column B and keep empty cells.

- I also made a small improvement by not translating the empty cells:

  `return [ c!=''?LanguageApp.translate(c, "ja", "en"):''];`

  this will boost the performance of the algorithm a little bit.
- In my case, given it is only one column and small dataset, I didn't need to use  `Utilities.sleep(1000);` but feel free to add it if you see issues with the script.

### Solutions:

**Apply to one sheet only with the name `Sheet1`:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const values = sheet.getRange('A1:A'+ sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const translatedValues = values.map(c=>{
//        Utilities.sleep(1000); // use it if you see errors in the script    
        return [ c!=''?LanguageApp.translate(c, "ja", "en"):''];
    });
  sheet.getRange(1,2,translatedValues.length).setValues(translatedValues);
}
```

**Apply to ALL sheets:**

```
 function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const values = sheet.getRange('A1:A'+ sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
    const translatedValues = values.map(c=>{
//        Utilities.sleep(1000); // use it if you see errors in the script
        return [ c!=''?LanguageApp.translate(c, "ja", "en"):''];
    });
    sheet.getRange(1,2,translatedValues.length).setValues(translatedValues);
  });
}
```